# Can I contribute my compiled software to the repos

Tags: updates, package-management, repository, contributing

So far I have seen many packages in the Ubuntu repository (e.g. Eclipse) which are old, so I have to compile and install it manually. So I wondered if I could contribute to Ubuntu and help to update some packages so not everybody has to manually install them? It may sound a bit naive but somebody has to do that, right?!
I am willing to learn if it is more complicated!

Comment: You are not naive, this is how open source works, anyone can contribute

Answer (score 0):

Some packages are updated by community members, but the bulk of the software in the Ubuntu repository are updated by Canonical.

They categorize their software broadly into **supported** and **unsupported**. Canonical provides updates for the former and community members can provide updates for the latter. See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#Package_classification_and_support) for more information on the classifications.

It appears that Eclipse specifically is unsupported free software, so the packages must be managed by a community member. I was unable to find out who exactly, but it is likely someone on the Eclipse development side. In any event, any packages in the Ubuntu repos have to go through a thorough approval process so it may be more involved than simply uploading a package you download from the source website.